# Packing C structs from PHP

Tags: php, c, struct, pack

I've played around with [`pack()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) for longer than I'd like to admit, and accidentally stumbled across [data structure alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment).  Is there a "good" way to create C structures from within PHP and account for these extra padding bytes?

I know that you can use "x" to inject NULL bytes, but how do you determine where these go and how many to use programmatically?

Along the same lines, which of these methods is better for modeling a `char foo[10]` array?

```
$struct = pack('a9x', $string);
// vs.
$struct = pack('a10', substr($string, 0, 9));
```

I believe they both accomplish the same thing, but I'm not sure of any potential pitfalls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you try to do is achievable, but highly dangerous. Let me explain:

- PHP code is largely independant from the Hardware/OS/C runtime it runs on
- (Portable) C **source** code mostly is also
- The compilation/linking/loading process of a C **binary** definitly is not (especially if you leave the padding/packing issues to the compiler)

Now what you try to do in PHP is a partial reimplementation of exactly this compilation/linking/loading process, but without a reliable mechanism to determine to adapt to  the environment.

I recommend one of two IMHO more reliable ways to do this:

- Write a PHP extension (this is rather easy), that does the structure-dependant stuff for you, including the headers from your C program. If you compile this on the target system (or  one with an equal environment) you will not run into the troubles above
- Chose another, higher level mechanism to communicate: We have successfully used SysV messages for a very similar requirement, but there are plenty of ways to go.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Under normal circumstances, I would choose not to do what I'm doing at all, but unfortunately, that's not an option.  I'm unable to recompile PHP on my target systems, so (I think) a PHP extension is out of the question.  I also have to maintain backwards compatibility with some legacy C binaries, and switching the messaging system would be... difficult.  :-)

Comment: Just on a side note: You do not need to recompile PHP to compile an extension. Just create a basic extension, run `phpize` and make. Even works on windows ...